# Pegar valor de uma entidade via propriedade de navegação

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma pergunta que parece básica, mas estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver.

Como posso pegar o valor de um atributo de uma entidade via Properties Navigations?

Por exemplo, tenho as classes:

```cs
public class Budget
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    ... // Outros atributos

    //Propriedade de Relacionamento
    public IEnumerable<BudgetItem> BudgetItems {get; set;}
}

public class BudgetItem
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string NameItem {get; set;}
    ... // Outros atributos

    //ForeingKey
    public Guid BudgetId {get; set;}

    //Propriedade de Navegação
    public Budget Budget {get; set;}
}
```

Em minha camada de Infra tenho todo o mapeamento. Funciona perfeito. O CRUD é realizado como previsto e no caso, é persistido no banco apenas os "Ids" da entidade. Nada fora do padrão. Acontece que, eu quero mostrar em minha View > Index uma lista de `BudgetItem`, sendo que cada um está relacionado a um `Budget`.

Na consulta normal é apresentado assim:

Tabela na View

**BudgetItem | Budget** (*Observação: é apresentado o Guid salvo*)
Item 1 | a6fa353b-e55b-42f3-92f2-17cecda4725d
Item 2 | c7b90b8e-4fd1-4422-8c11-bb5fbaae7f05

O que preciso é que mostre desse jeito:

**BudgetItem | Budget**
Item 1 | Nome do Orçamento
Item 2 | Nome do Orçamento

Em outras aplicações (EF6 e Windows Forms) eu apenas carregava fazendo uma consulta simples tipo:

```cs
public IEnumerable<BudgetItem> GetByBudgetName(budgetName)
{
   return _context.ButgetItem.Where(c => c.Budget.Name.Equals(budgetName));
}
```

No entanto no ASP.NET Core 2.0 isso não funciona. Simplesmente não consigo acessar dados de outra classe/tabela por meio das propriedades de navegação.

Segue minha View:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BudgetItem)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BudgetId)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Value)</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in(IEnumerable
    <BudgetItemViewModel>)ViewBag.ListBudget) {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Month)</td>        
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BudgetId)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Value)</td>
      </tr>
      }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Eu preciso substituir a linha `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BudgetId)</td>` de forma que ao invés de mostrar o "Id" mostre a descrição (nome) do Budget correspondente.

Considerando que isso é uma FK, em minha classe tenho a Propriedade de Navegação para a mesma. Logo eu pensei que funcionaria assim `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget.Name)</td>`.

Os nobres amigos poderiam me ajudar com isso?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Uma dúvida, pra mim esse tipo de cláusula não funciona mesmo `c => c.Budget.Name.Equals(budgetName)`, se trocar por `c => c.Budget.Name == budgetName` não resolveria todo seu problema?

Comment: Na verdade, tanto com o Equals ou "==" dá no mesmo. O meu retorno sempre vem vazio. Tentei fazer "join", mas retorna vazio tbm.

Comment: O Equals aparentemente não é interpretado pela montagem da query pra mim, nao entendo o que acontece.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Mas, independente, existe uma outra maneira de buscar os dados que preciso para minha View? A classe apenas grava o "Id" do Budget. Só preciso que na minha View seja apresentado o valor (Nome) do Budget ao invés da string salva como "Id".

Comment: Amigo, tente fazer o `include`, que funciona como o `join`, assim: `return _context.ButgetItem.Include(p=> p.Budget ).Where(c => c.Budget.Name.Equals(budgetName));` e na view acesse a propriedade, estou pelo celular, já gero uma resposta.

Comment: E o que aparece quando você usa `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Budget.Name)</td>`? A sua propriedade `item.Budget` realmente possui a referência ao objeto `Budget` correto? Consegue confirmar isso?