# Preciso pegar o valor das Propriedades de Navegação

Tags: asp.net-core, linq-to-sql

Amigos, como faço para mostrar em minha View uma informação por meio de uma propriedade de navegação, tipo:

**Minha View:**

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mes)</th>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PlanoDeContasId)</th>
          <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Valor)</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable
        <PoolAnalysisDfpAccountViewModel>)ViewBag.ListaPagina1) {
          <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mes)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlanoDeContasId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)</td>
            <td>
              //Links para outras áreas da aplicação
            </td>
          </tr>
          }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Dessa forma o campo "PlanoDeContasId" é apresentado o Guid salvo no banco. O que preciso é que seja apresentado o "nome do Plano de Contas". Eu pensei que se utilizasse a **propriedade de navegação** de minha ViewModel eu conseguisse obter a informação. Tipo, eu pensei em fazer algo assim:

```html
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PlanoDeContas.Nome)</td>
```

Mas isso simplesmente deixa o campo em branco.

Então, como pegar o valor da propriedade de navegação? Gostaria de fazer isso na Controller e depois passar já o resultado para a View.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Pegar valor de uma entidade via propriedade de navegação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/337120/pegar-valor-de-uma-entidade-via-propriedade-de-navega%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0):

Como já respondido em outro tópico parecido, basta apenas gerar uma consulta com o método Include tipo:

```html
public IEnumerable<Orcamento> FindAll()
{
    return DbSet.Include(p > p.PlanoDeContas).Where(c => c.OrcamentoId > 0).ToList();
}
```